# jQuery UI Custom Min Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> Facing issue in jquery Uncaught TypeError: a.ui.isOverAxis is not a
>   function in jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-1.10.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

please check the error message below

```
jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: a.ui.isOverAxis is not a function
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._intersectsWithPointer (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:37:8557)
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:37:5411)
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseStart (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:37:3580)
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:13:1847)
at HTMLDocument._mouseMoveDelegate (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js:13:1403)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3:4816)
at HTMLDocument.i (http://localhost:13043/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3:709)
```

Comment: Why are you adding jquery-1.10.0.js as well as jquery-1.7.2.min.js ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ???? Can Add some code or jsfisdle something ???

Comment: please  understand the script file,usually i update the both Base JQuery Library File and ui library file in Layout View

Comment: can you resolve the issue a.ui.isOverAxis is not a function error message